# Strange behavior of C programs

Tags: c

Following is my C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;

    do
    {
        printf("\n1.create\n2.display\n3.exit\n\t");
        printf("Enter your choice:: ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        printf("choice = %d\n\n", ch);
        if(ch==32767)
            return 0;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n Case 1 executed\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nCase 2 executed\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nExit\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong choice!!!");
                break;

        }
    }while(ch!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is that when I am inputting integer value for ch it is working fine.
But when I am inputting any characters it is running in infinite loop.

Can any one solve it.

Comment: Run it through a debugger and then get back here if you don't understand what is happening. If you're on Linux, I'd recommend GDB...

Comment: @Prabin Why do you want to input 'ch' as an integer type? Would you need that number later for some further processing? If no, then using `int` to parse not-strictly-integer input might not be the best solution. If you need the value for something other than `switch-case`, would inputing as a character/string be an option, and then extracting the integer value in case of a correct input? In any case, I strongly recommend not using _only_ `int` type for input in case of possible non-numerical input.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `scanf ("%*[^\n]\n");`

Here you have used **scanf("%d",&ch);** which will read integer value correctly but as soon as you will give any value other then integer it will terminate or show different output. 
`Why this is happening ?` 
@It's happning because each time you entered some value either valid or invalid first it place in input buffer reader after that value read from there..

For further Info regarding scanf : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;

    do
    {
        printf("\n1.create\n2.display\n3.exit\n\t");
        printf("Enter your choice:: ");

        scanf ("%*[^\n]\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n Case 1 executed\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nCase 2 executed\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nExit\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong choice!!!");
                break;

        }
    }while(ch!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nishant, Thanks for posting the answer. I found a problem after running this code. When it is asking for input and, I am inserting a character it is showing blank. Again if I enter a character it is working fine. Can you fix it.

Comment: This code is not working. Example: try typing in 'j1E' 'jE' '1E' 'jE' where 'E' stands for the enter key. What happens after each enter: nothing, wrong_choice, case_1, case_1 . I don't think that is a desired behavior. Am I wrong?

Comment: That answer is a bit misleading: The pattern "%*[^\n]" will discard everything before (not including) a newline. If there is nothing before the newline, it will simply fail, and the next pattern won't be executed. If there is something before the newline, it gets discarded and then "\n" gets executed, which will discard every whitespace character up to a non-whitespace character. If there isn't any non-whitespace character after the newline `scanf` will be hanging expecting one

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `char` value instead of an `int` if you want to be able to handle characters.

In that case, you also have to modify your `switch-case` statement, because `'1'` - a character, is different than `1` - an integer number.  Corrected code should be something like:

```
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;

    do
    {
        printf("\n1.create\n2.display\n3.exit\n\t");
        printf("Enter your choice:: ");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        printf("choice = %c\n\n", ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
                printf("\n Case 1 executed\n");
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("\nCase 2 executed\n");
                break;
            // case 32767: - can not be stored in a char variable
            case 127:
            case CHAR_MAX: // these two are almost equivalent, but the
                           // second one is better because it relies on
                           // library defined constant from limits.h
            case '3':
                printf("\nExit\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 'a':
                printf("\nA character case accepted!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong choice!!!");
                break;

        }
    }while();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I also excluded the break condition from as the `while()` argument, because it is redundant - it will already be checked inside the `switch` statement.

I also added a non-error case of parsing a character so that you can see an example of that.

One other note: Your old code should accept both `01` and `1` as a valid choice, while the new code will parse `01` as two different choices (1 choice == 1 character):

- `0` will be parsed as a wrong choice
- `1` will be parsed as a correct choice for case 1

I have also commented on some other things from your code in the code comments in the corrected code snippets. I took out the "impossible" if (as Jerry Coffin pointed out in the comments), and put it in a more appropriate place, replacing the constant in to something meaningful.

Comment: At least on most systems (where CHAR_MAX = 127 or 255) the comparison to 32767 can't possibly be true.

Comment: @Fredrik That's true, I usually don't answer this kind of questions with code-replies... Just felt especially nice today :)

Comment: Hi penelope, According to your answer I should declare ch as character type. But I want it to be of integer.Can you say how to free the memory location used by scanf. I think if we can free the memory used by scanf then the problem is solved.

Comment: @Prabin free the memory location? The memory location where `scanf` stores it's inputs is reserved while declaring a variable -- `int ch;` or `char ch;` I'm not sure what do you mean by _freeing_ said memory -- it's reserved for your variable, if you didn't want the variable at all you shouldn't have declared it in the first place :confused:

Comment: @Question is not about to find alternative solution by using another data type..he want's solution by declaring int data type..

Comment: @Nishant Then that should be stated somewhere. For me "it's not working" means it's not displaying desired behaviour when it runs, and "it works!" means, "oh yes, it finally is!!", no matter what the program code. I can understand doing it for learning purposes, but then the question should clearly say: "I want to do these things by inputing in to a integer variable" This way, it's open to interpretation until the question-asker specifies it better

Comment: @penelope: See there comment dear....Hi penelope, According to your answer I should declare ch as character type. But I want it to be of integer.Can you say how to free the memory location used by scanf. I think if we can free the memory used by scanf then the problem is solved.......Still you are waiting for confirmation for putting in question that he wants to do only by using Integer....